# Rollback on failure of Firebase storage upload

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, firebase-storage

My goal is to have a firebase cloud function track the upload of three separate files to the same storage bucket.  These uploads are preceded by a write to the real time database which would preferably be the trigger for the cloud function to track the uploads.

The context is a user is adding an item to her shopping cart.  The data is written to the RTDB and then a custom 3d model and 2 images are copied into a storage bucket.  If any of these files don't successfully upload, I need to know that and conduct a rollback of the 3 files in the storage bucket and also remove the entry in the database.  I could handle this client side, but that isn't ideal since usually if the uploads fail, its because the connection with the client has failed.

I haven't been able to find any sort of batch add or transaction-type uploads to firebase storage.  Sorry for not having any code to show, but I'm not even really sure how to get started on this.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you nest your writes? e.g. write file 1, if success, the write file 2, if fail, delete write 1. Continue to write file 3 and if fail, delete 2 and 1. If 3 success then write url's to RTDB?

Comment: I would prefer to have it all handled server side since if an upload fails, it is likely due to connection issues.  If there are connection issues, there aren't any guarantees that the delete will go through.

Answer (score 0):

There are no transactions that cross products like this.  Nor are there any transactions offered by Cloud Storage.  You're going to have to check errors and manually undo things previously done.  Or, have some job that checks for orphaned data and deletes it later.